# falling bottle not falling

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, game-physics

I want to create a game of falling objects. In this case I have only one bottle and i want it to fall but it's not working. As you can see in the picture, the bottle starts to distort, it's not falling. Thanks!

```
   function bottleCreate(e:Event):void {

    var bottleNew:MovieClip;

    bottleNew = newBottle();
        bottleNew.x = 100;
        bottleNew.y=0;

    addChild(bottleNew);
bottle.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bottleMove);
}

function bottleMove(e:Event):void {
        e.target.y ++;          
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bottleCreate);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the event listener for bottleCreate function, by 
 adding

> stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bottleCreate);

to your bottleCreate function.

Or

Call bottleCreate function once , instead of using

> stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bottleCreate);

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't get distorted. You are adding new bottle every frame with (100,0) so it looks like it is distorted but actually there is a new instance every 1 pixel

call bottleCreate() only once